# bookmap element type is not working

Tags: dita

```
{?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?}
{!DOCTYPE bookmap PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA 1.3 Bookmap//EN"     "technicalContent/dtd/bookmap.dtd"}
{bookmap xml:lang="en-us"}
{booktitle}
{booklibrary}Books about stuff{/booklibrary}
{mainbooktitle}A book about one thing{/mainbooktitle}
{/booktitle}
{bookmeta}
{bookrights}
{copyrfirst}{year}1994{/year}{/copyrfirst}
{copyrlast}{year}2006{/year}{/copyrlast}
{bookowner}OASIS{/bookowner}
{/bookrights}
{/bookmeta}
{frontmatter}
{booklists}
{toc/}
{figurelist/} 
{tablelist/}
{/booklists}
{bookabstract href="MyBookAbstract.dita"/}
{preface href="preface.dita"}{/preface}
{/frontmatter}
{chapter href="chapter1.dita"}
{topicref href="subchap1.dita"}{/topicref}
{/chapter}
{chapter href="chapter2.dita"}
{topicref href="subchap2.dita"}{/topicref}
{/chapter}
{appendix href="app1.dita"}
{topicref href="insideApp1.dita"}{/topicref}
{/appendix}
{appendix href="app2.dita"}
{topicref href="insideApp2.dita"}{/topicref}
{/appendix}
{backmatter}
{amendments href="updatesToTheBook.dita"/}
{booklists}
{trademarklist href="listoftrademarks.dita"/}
{indexlist/}
{/booklists}
{/backmatter}
{/bookmap}

   This file is map.ditamap.
```

The error I am getting is

> C:\dita-samples\bookmap>dita -i map.ditamap -f pdf -o output
>
> Error: Failed to run pipeline: [DOTA069F][FATAL] Input file 'file:/C:/dita-samples/bookmap/map.ditamap' cannot be located or read.
>   Ensure that file was specified properly and that you have permission to access it.

Comment: Thanks...issue resolved

Comment: How was this issue resolved? There is now answer to to this question.